# Why threads are working in this order?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 3 classes: **Main**, **Caller** and **CallMe**. **Caller** implements **Runnable**. I pass to **Caller** constuctor a pointer to instance of **CallMe** and a message that **Caller** pass to method of instance of **CallMe** which print the message. Next, I start a thread.

In **Main** I create 3 instances of **Caller** and I except that here it will be printed:

```
[Welcome]
[to synchronized]
[world!]
```

But I get the following result:

```
[Welcome]
[world!]
[to synchronized]
```

**Why?**

***There is the code:***

*Main.java*

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CallMe target = new CallMe();
        Caller ob1 = new Caller(target, "Welcome");
        Caller ob2 = new Caller(target, "to synchronized");
        Caller ob3 = new Caller(target, "world!");

        try {
            ob1.thread.join();
            ob2.thread.join();
            ob3.thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

*Caller.java*

```
public class Caller implements Runnable {
    String message;
    CallMe target;
    Thread thread;

    public Caller(CallMe target, String message) {
        this.target = target;
        this.message = message;
        this.thread = new Thread(this);
        this.thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (target) {
            target.call(message);
        }
    }
}
```

*CallMe.java*

```
public class CallMe {    
    public void call(String msg) {
        System.out.print("[" + msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect them to run in a certain order? Creating them sequentially does not guarantee that they will execute sequentially.

Comment: @DanielGibbs I thought that by creating them in the order I set the order of execution of threads.

Comment: No, not at all. Have a read of the [Java concurrency guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three instantiations of `Caller` in your main method probably all happen within one time slice, i.e. without yielding to another thread.  This results in all three threads being created and placed into the runnable state.  After that, threads can be scheduled in any order, so you just got unlucky.

If you want threads to execute in a specific order you need to provide the interlocking logic yourself.

Comment: @AndyTurner of course, but I assumed this was self-education in multithreaded programming.

Comment: I think "just do it in one thread!" is a very useful thing to learn to consider as an option.